# How do you get the type from a cursor?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

The javadocs indicate that android.database.Cursor has a getType(int) method.  However, when I try to call this method, Eclipse gives me an error saying no method exists.   What gives?

Comment: Are you sure the import was done correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of Android are you targeting? The `getType()` method applies only to v3.0 and later.

**EDIT:** Assuming you're targeting pre v3.0 versions of Android then a possible 'hack' to discover the type of each column within a table would be to query the sqlite_master table to find the CREATE data.

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master
```

It's pretty nasty but if you really need to find the type then you could extend SQLiteCursor and add your own `getType(int columnIndex)` method.

You could perform a one-off query to the `sqlite_master` table when the cursor first accesses a table then parse the `CREATE` statement from the `sql` column and store the 'types' in an `int[]`.

In the `getType(int columnIndex)` you would simply return the value of your `int[]` based on `columnindex`.

As I said, bit of a hack but it would work.

Comment: Ah,ha!  You are correct.  I'm targeting v1.5.  When looking at the Javadocs, I wasn't filtering by the appropriate API level (duh).  Yes, I'll have to extend the cursor class as you suggest or come up with a different solution.  What I'm ultimately try to do is dynamically create odata posts using the odata4j library.  Another solution would be to just code a per-table solution.   Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SBerg413: Glad to be of help. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

As you can store any type of data in (nearly) every SQLite field. Looking up the data type in sqlite_master and by using the pragma command is not a safe method. You can get the type of the fields using a query like this:

```
select Field1, typeof(Field1), Field2, typeof(Field2) from MyTable
```

This statement returns both the value of the fields and their types which might / might not change from record to record.

Comment: The intention was to get the expected value in order to create an oData xml structure to post to a server.  So, unfortunately, your solution is problematic.   Both previous answers are a better solution.

Comment: In my work with SQLite databases on the Android platform (the aSQLiteManager) I have learned the hard way not to rely on expectations ;-)