# Android Cursor? how to read object data?

Tags: android, sqlite, casting, android-cursor, getstring

i know a `Cursor` has method for get `String, Int`, etc
but isn't there somethings as

```
mycursor.GetObject(index)
```

I want to create a dynamic method which returns an object and I only cast it.

or is it possible use 
`mycursor.GetString(index)` for any type?  `String,Float,Double,Long,Short, Blob,Int`,etc

and I can use for example for a `Float` or a `Int` or any type and cast it?

for example

```
(Blob) newblob=mycursor.GetString(i_return_BloB);
(Int) newint=mycursor.GetString(i_return_Int);
(Float) newfloat=mycursor.GetString(i_return_Float);
(Double) newdouble=mycursor.GetString(i_return_Double);
(Long) newlong=mycursor.GetString(i_return_long);
(Short) newshort=mycursor.GetString(i_return_short);
```

would it work?
could i use `mycursor.GetString()` for any type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [get the type of a column](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getType%28int%29), and then call the appropiate method from a `switch` statement (and build the method you're asking for by yourself).

Using `getString` for different types is not safe, as the docs specify:

> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.

Comment: android.database.Cursor does not have getType() that was my idea using a swich or if but it does not have GetType(columnindex)

Comment: Available on apilevel >= 11... seems like there is no suitable method for older Androids, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658239/cursor-gettype-for-api-level-11

Answer (score 2):

You want to try something like:

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] array;

Cursor c = myDbHelper.query(query);

int id = c.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NAME");

for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    mArrayList.add(c.getString(id));
}

array = mArrayList.toArray(new String[0]);


System.out.println(array[0]);

c.close();

myDbHelper.close();
```

And your `query()` should look something like:

```
public Cursor query(String query){

    String selectAll = null;

    if(query.length() > 1){

    selectAll = "SELECT TABLENAME.COLUMNAME FROM TABLENAME WHERE TABLENAME.COLUMNNAME LIKE" + query + ";";

    return myDataBase.rawQuery(selectAll, null);
}
```

You need to change the SQL code to suit your needs. In this case I'm retrieving every value of a column that match the query, but you could modify the `SELECT` statement. Hope it helps.