# Cursor.getType() API < 11 Issues

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658239/cursor-gettype-for-api-level-11) suggested by @JuanSánchez but I have come across an issue.

My issue is a `ClassCastException` when trying to cast the `android.database.Cursor` object (c) to `CursorWrapper`. More specifically the line of code as so `CursorWrapper cw = (CursorWrapper)c;`.

```
        CursorWindow cursorWindow = null;
        int cursorPosition = 0;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            CursorWrapper cw = (CursorWrapper)c;
            Class<?> cursorWrapper = CursorWrapper.class;
            Field mCursor = null;
            try {
                mCursor = cursorWrapper.getDeclaredField("mCursor");
                mCursor.setAccessible(true);
                AbstractWindowedCursor abstractWindowedCursor = (AbstractWindowedCursor)mCursor.get(cw);
                cursorWindow = abstractWindowedCursor.getWindow();
                cursorPosition = abstractWindowedCursor.getPosition();
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Any help I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out. Super simple.

Swap out the following lines.

**Swap** `CursorWrapper cw = (CursorWrapper)cursor;`

**For** `CursorWrapper cw = new CursorWrapper(cursor);`

Comment: You could also have done `CursorWindow cursorWindow = ((AbstractWindowedCursor)cursor).getWindow();`.